# Crossword Solving Companion

Tags: python, crossword

I am writing a program that takes letters and indexes and spits out crossword answers (not a crossword solver, but a tool to aid in solving crosswords, if that makes sense).

I've written two versions of the algorithm, but neither seems to work correctly. The first one I tried was this:

```
fin = open('words.txt')

def answer_finder():
    global fin
    possible_answers = []
    length = int(raw_input("How long is the word?"))
    letter_1 = raw_input("What is the first letter that you know?").lower
    letter_1_index = int(raw_input("How many letters into the word is that letter?")) - 1
    letter_2 = raw_input("What is the second letter that you know?").lower
    letter_2_index = int(raw_input("How many letters into the word is that letter?")) - 1
    letter_3 = raw_input("What is the third letter that you know?").lower
    letter_3_index = int(raw_input("How many letters into the word is that letter?")) - 1
    for i in fin:
        if len(i) == length:
            if i[letter_1_index] == letter_1 and i[letter_2_index] == letter_2 and i[letter_3_index] == letter_3:
                possible_answers.append(i)
    return possible_answers
```

I realize it's kinda ugly, but this was more of a proof of concept for the algorithm. The user input will be changed later. Anyway, this seems to return an empty list no matter what I try.

The second version was essentially the same, but relied on nested if statements instead of boolean operators:

```
def answer_finder():
    global fin
    possible_answers = []
    length = int(raw_input("How long is the word?"))
    letter_1 = raw_input("What is the first letter that you know?").lower
    letter_1_index = int(raw_input("How many letters into the word is that letter?")) - 1
    letter_2 = raw_input("What is the second letter that you know?").lower
    letter_2_index = int(raw_input("How many letters into the word is that letter?")) - 1
    letter_3 = raw_input("What is the third letter that you know?").lower
    letter_3_index = int(raw_input("How many letters into the word is that letter?")) - 1
    for i in fin:
        if len(i) == length:
            if i[letter_1_index] == letter_1:
                if i[letter_2_index] == letter_2:
                    if i[letter_3_index] == letter_3:
                        possible_answers.append(i)
    return possible_answers
```

This, too, returns an empty list. The list of words I am using comes from [here](http://thinkpython.com/code/words.txt). I'm assuming I am missing something obvious, since I'm new to working with external files. I should point out that these functions are prototypes of the former, and both work just fine:

```
def greater_than_20():
    global fin
    li = []
    for i in fin:
        if len(i) > 20:
            li.append(i)
    return li

def first_letter_length_finder():
    global fin
    length = int(raw_input("How long is the word?"))
    first_letter = raw_input("What is the first letter?")
    li = []
    for i in fin:
        if len(i) == length and i[0] == first_letter:
            li.append(i)
    print li
    return li
```

EDIT: Just for reference, here is the code in its entirety (including commented-out sections of code.)

```
fin = open('words.txt')
print fin

def greater_than_20():
    global fin
    li = []
    for i in fin:
        if len(i) > 20:
            li.append(i)
    return li

def first_letter_length_finder():
    global fin
    length = int(raw_input("How long is the word?"))
    first_letter = raw_input("What is the first letter?")
    li = []
    for i in fin:
        if len(i) == length and i[0] == first_letter:
            li.append(i)
    print li
    return li

def answer_finder():
    global fin
    possible_answers = []
    length = int(raw_input("How long is the word?"))
    letter_1 = raw_input("What is the first letter that you know?").lower
    letter_1_index = int(raw_input("How many letters into the word is that letter?")) - 1
    letter_2 = raw_input("What is the second letter that you know?").lower
    letter_2_index = int(raw_input("How many letters into the word is that letter?")) - 1
    letter_3 = raw_input("What is the third letter that you know?").lower
    letter_3_index = int(raw_input("How many letters into the word is that letter?")) - 1
    for i in fin:
        if len(i) == length:
#            if i[letter_1_index] == letter_1 and i[letter_2_index] == letter_2 and i[letter_3_index] == letter_3:
#                possible_answers.append(i)
            if i[letter_1_index] == letter_1:
                if i[letter_2_index] == letter_2:
                    if i[letter_3_index] == letter_3:
                        possible_answers.append(i)
    return possible_answers
```

Comment: You don't appear to be splitting the word file up (or even reading from it)...is this done in code you didn't post?

Comment: Oh, possibly. All of these functions are in the same document, and I have, at the top, `fin = open('words.txt')`. I'm then calling `global fin` into each of the functions. I'm still super new with reading files through Python, so if that's not the way it's supposed to be done, please let me know. I added he full code for the program so far for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `string.lower` method, but you missed the `()`.

```
>>> letter_3 = raw_input("What is the third letter that you know?").lower
What is the third letter that you know?a
>>> letter_3
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x104e514e0>

>>> letter_3 = raw_input("What is the third letter that you know?").lower()
What is the third letter that you know?a
>>> letter_3
'a'
```

Without the parentheses, you are assigning not the *value* of the `.lower` function, but the function itself.

EDIT: For the record (because I can't leave comments), your method of using `for i in fin` is fine, since files are iterable, delimited by `\n`.

Comment: Oh. Man. Good eyes. I must have read past that a hundred times. Thanks a bunch. The code works perfectly now. Is there a difference between the two versions of the algorithm in terms of performance? nested ifs vs boolean operators? Mostly curious, since it doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: There isn't much difference in algorithmic performance because the heaviest stuff is actually going through the file of words, which both approach does at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read you data out of the file first before trying to use the data.

```
fin = file('words.txt').readlines ()
```

Comment: This has made the code super slow to load, and `answer_finder` is still returning an empty list. Is there a method I should call in the function to read the lines? If so, why does `first_letter_length_finder` (I really need to fix that name) work when it does essentially the same thing with less input?